# How to change block shipping Address to select box ? Magento2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, drop-downs

I want to change format of Shipping Addresses in Checkout page to dropdown.
Anybody here can help me for this case?

https://prnt.sc/kcqtnl

Comment: Sounds like knockoutjs duty.